# How To Get Value of the Same Row

Tags: javascript, asp.net

I have some data in this table. When i edit the Percentage, how can i get the value of the Supply Quantity?

Below is my ASPX code:

```
  <asp:GridView ID="grdSupplierItem" runat="server" AutoGenerateColumns="False" CssClass="Gridview3">
                                        <Columns>
                                            <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Supplier">
                                                <ItemTemplate>
                                                    <asp:Label ID="lblAutoNum" Visible="false" Text='<%# Eval("AutoNum") %>' runat="server" />
                                                    <asp:DropDownList ID="ddlSupplier" runat="server" CssClass="form-control width250">
                                                    </asp:DropDownList>
                                                </ItemTemplate>
                                            </asp:TemplateField>
                                            <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Sequence">
                                                <ItemStyle HorizontalAlign="Right"></ItemStyle>
                                                <ItemTemplate>
                                                    <asp:TextBox CssClass="form-control numbertext" onkeypress="return onlyNumber(event)" Width="80px" ID="txtSequence" Text='<%#String.Format("{0:n0}", DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem, "Sequence")) %>' runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
                                                </ItemTemplate>
                                            </asp:TemplateField>
                                            <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Percentage (%)">
                                                <ItemStyle HorizontalAlign="Right"></ItemStyle>
                                                <ItemTemplate>
                                                    <asp:TextBox CssClass="form-control numbertext" onkeyup="javascript:text_changed(this);" ID="txtPercentage" AutoPostBack="false" OnTextChanged="txtPercentage_TextChanged" Text='<%# DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem, "SupplyPercentage") %>' runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
                                                </ItemTemplate>
                                            </asp:TemplateField>
                                            <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Effective Date">
                                                <ItemTemplate>
                                                    <asp:TextBox CssClass="form-control datepicker" ID="txtEffectiveDate" data-provide="datepicker" runat="server" Width="120px"></asp:TextBox>
                                                </ItemTemplate>
                                            </asp:TemplateField>
                                            <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Expired Date">
                                                <ItemTemplate>
                                                    <asp:TextBox CssClass="form-control datepicker" ID="txtExpiredDate" data-provide="datepicker" runat="server" Width="120px"></asp:TextBox>
                                                </ItemTemplate>
                                            </asp:TemplateField>
                                            <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Unit Price(RM)">
                                                <ItemStyle HorizontalAlign="Right"></ItemStyle>
                                                <ItemTemplate>
                                                    <asp:TextBox CssClass="form-control numbertext text-right" OnTextChanged="txtUnitPrice_TextChanged" onkeypress="return isNumber(event)" ID="txtUnitPrice" AutoPostBack="true" Text='<%# DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem, "SellingPrice") %>' runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
                                                </ItemTemplate>
                                            </asp:TemplateField>
                                            <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Supply Qty">
                                                <ItemStyle HorizontalAlign="Right"></ItemStyle>
                                                <ItemTemplate>
                                                    <asp:TextBox CssClass="form-control numbertext text-right" OnTextChanged="txtSupplyQty_TextChanged" AutoPostBack="true" onkeypress="return isNumber(event)" ID="txtSupplyQty" Text='<%# DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem, "SupplyQty") %>' runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
                                                </ItemTemplate>
                                            </asp:TemplateField>
                                            <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Supply Value">
                                                <ItemStyle HorizontalAlign="Right"></ItemStyle>
                                                <ItemTemplate>
                                                    <asp:TextBox CssClass="form-control numbertext text-right" OnTextChanged="txtSupplyValue_TextChanged" AutoPostBack="true" onkeypress="return isNumber(event)" ID="txtSupplyValue" Text='<%# DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem, "SupplyValue") %>' runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
                                                </ItemTemplate>
                                            </asp:TemplateField>
                                            <asp:ButtonField Text="&lt;img border=0 src=ImageFile/Delete1.gif&gt;" CommandName="Delete">
                                                <ItemStyle HorizontalAlign="Center"></ItemStyle>
                                            </asp:ButtonField>
                                        </Columns>
                                        <RowStyle CssClass="gridrow" />
                                        <SelectedRowStyle CssClass="gridheader" />
                                        <HeaderStyle CssClass="gridheader" />
                                        <AlternatingRowStyle CssClass="gridRowAlt" />
                                    </asp:GridView>
```

I had tried with this JS and only manage to get the value of Percentage(%)

```
     function text_changed(textObj) {
     value = textObj.value;
     var $otherInput = 
     textObj.closest('tr').find('input[id$="txtSupplyQty"]');
    }
```

I need to do some calculation on the Javascript Code.

Comment: Take a look at the HTML. The ID is not `txtSupplyQty`...

Comment: it definitely is txtSupplyQty

Comment: It is definitely not. If it would mean you have duplicate id's in html.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The ID for your `<asp:TextBox />` will change once your client receives the page.

You'll need to get the client's text box ID in a different way if you're doing it in JavaScript. If you're using jQuery, it'll look something like this:

```js
const textBox = $find('<%= txtSupplyQty.ClientID %>');
```

But beyond that, the web form controls do not support the `onkeyup` event listener like you have defined here.

If you really want to attach an `onkeyup` event, you'll have to either manually attach an event listener in a script block like I just mentioned above or you'll have to do it in your code behind.

If you're attaching an event listener in code behind, you can it to your `Page_Load`:

```cs
txtPercentage.Attributes.Add("onKeyUp", "text_changed(this)");
```

Comment: i get this : error BC30451: 'txtSupplyQty' is not declared. It may be inaccessible due to its protection level.

Comment: Are you defining `txtSupplyQty` in your code behind? Either it's not defined in your code behind, or it's declared as a `private` object and it needs to at least be a `protected` object.

Comment: how should i define it?  Protected txtSupplyQty As Integer ?

Comment: If you're using VB: `Protected txtSupplyQty As TextBox`
If you're using C#: `protected TextBox txtSupplyQty;`

Comment: ok the event listener is working just nice. How should i add the text_changed function?

Comment: You'll want to add that to a script block on your aspx/ascx page. Put something like this near the bottom of your page. `<script> function text_changed(event) { /* Do Something */ } </script>`